# What is the best way to test download using selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am new to selenium, I understand two ways to test download file

1) simply call web element click

2) taking download link and test whether file exist or not

my question is which is better way or is there any another method???

Answer (score 1):

You have to be more specific about your question, but as far as Download functionality is concerned in a browser, you set a Browser Profile, so that it would download the files automatically in the desired location. you can use this code:

```
 FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();

firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList",2);
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",false);
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.dir","c:\\downloads");
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","text/csv");

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);//new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), capability);

driver.navigate().to("http://www.yourpage.com/");
```